# Как сделать выбор качества видео?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Будет передаваться такая ссылка `[низкое]//site.com/360p.mp4, [среднее]//site.com/720p.mp4, [высокое]//site.com/1080p.mp4` и моя задача стоит такая, что нужно каким-то образом получать ссылку по выбору качества. Я в регулярных выражениях честно говоря вообще не силен. Можете пожалуйста помочь? И еще один вопрос, если не трудно ответить. При смене качества мне нужно всего лишь получать текущее время, потом менять ссылку и устанавливать время? Спасибо

Comment: `'[низкое]//site.com/360p.mp4, [среднее]//site.com/720p.mp4, [высокое]//site.com/1080p.mp4'.match(/(?<=\[среднее\])(.*?)(?=,|$)/)[1]`